# Android EditText - Character Placeholder

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to achieve an `EditText` implementation for filling out 4 digits that the user receives via text message.

The `EditText` should display an underline for every character missing, the underline should vanish when the user types a character, and reappear when the user deletes a character.

Here are some illustrations to get the concept:

```
Default mode: _ _ _ _

Some characters entered: 1 2 _ _

All characters entered: 1 2 3 4
```

I was wondering if there was a straightforward method of implementing such a thing with an `EditText`, or would I need to implement some custom view to achieve an effect like this.

Comment: I can only think of `TextWatcher` to achieve this.

Comment: You mean adding a TextWatcher via the EditText's addTextChangedListener? Not sure how this would work... I can't set the EditText's text with underlines because when the user would grab focus on the EditText he would be pushed to the end of the text. Hint wouldn't work either, since it would vanish when the user begins adding text.

Comment: Yeah...I was thinking of putting the "_ _ _ _ " as text in the `EditText` and keep adding the text to the beginning as the user enters text. But, you are right, the focus would come out at the end each time and it would appear as a cheap hack.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I just found a library that you can use for that purpose:

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Search for "Material Code input" and you will find a component ready to be used

I hope it was helpful